# simpleform and country_select with iso_codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using a Ruby on Rails gem called simple_form with country_select and I'm trying to get the drop down to display the long country name but set the value to the short iso code.

If I have the following

```
= f.input :country, priority: ["Australia", "United States", "New Zealand"]
```

Then all the countries after my priority countries are correct (displaying the fullname whilst using the iso_code for the value). The priority countries though use the name as the label & value. Is there a way to set the ISO code on the priority countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into simple_form source is a real PITA because it is so incredible abstract. But from what I can see, this seems to be an issue with using the [CountrySelect Gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select).

The gem says that you should use `iso_codes: true` to make sure the code is used as a key. I guess that you will have to digg into how the `priority` parameters get handled or try passing this option through to the gem.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  def country_options_for_select(selected = nil, priority_countries = nil, use_iso_codes = false)
    country_options = "".html_safe

    if priority_countries
      priority_countries_options = if use_iso_codes || ::CountrySelect.use_iso_codes
                                     priority_countries.map do |code|
                                       [
                                         ::CountrySelect::COUNTRIES[code],
                                         code
                                       ]
                                     end
                                   else
                                     priority_countries
                                   end

      country_options += options_for_select(priority_countries_options, selected)
      country_options += "<option value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\">-------------</option>\n".html_safe
      #
      # prevents selected from being included
      # twice in the HTML which causes
      # some browsers to select the second
      # selected option (not priority)
      # which makes it harder to select an
      # alternative priority country
      #
      selected = nil if priority_countries.include?(selected)
    end

    values = if use_iso_codes || ::CountrySelect.use_iso_codes
               ::CountrySelect::ISO_COUNTRIES_FOR_SELECT
             else
               ::CountrySelect::COUNTRIES_FOR_SELECT
             end

    return country_options + options_for_select(values.sort, selected)
  end
```

Comment: Had to upgrade my gem, use lower case alpha2 codes only and include iso_codes: true on my select line. Works through simple_form.

Answer (score 2):

You can set

```
::CountrySelect.use_iso_codes = true
```

in an initializer to globally use the ISO codes as dropdown values instead of country names.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/country_select/1.3.1/frames

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `iso_codes: true` to your field:

```
= f.input :country, priority: ["Australia", "United States", "New Zealand"], iso_codes: true
```

*Tested with simple_form 3.1.0.rc2 and country_select 1.3.1*